# Do C++ compilers avoid copying when returning by value?

Tags: c++, copy, return-value, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
LargeObject getLargeObject()
{
    LargeObject glo;
    // do some initialization stuff with glo
    return glo;
}

void test()
{
    LargeObject tlo = getLargeObject();
    // do sth. with tlo;
}
```

A simple compiler would create a local LargeObject glo on the getLargeObject() stack and then assign it to tlo in test() when returning, which involves a copy operation.

But shouldn't a clever compiler realize that glo is going to be assigned to tlo and thus just use tlo's memory in the first place to avoid the copy operation? Resulting in something (functionally) like:

```
void getLargeObject(LargeObject &lo)
{
    // do init stuff
}

void test()
{
    LargeObject lo;
    getLargeObject(lo);
}
```

My guess is, that compilers do something similar. But can it always be done? Are there situations where it can't be optimized like that? How can I know if my return value is copied or not?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: that's an answer!

Comment: A link to an article is not an answer.

Comment: -1: This question clearly shows no research effort - this topic is covered all over the internet.

Comment: While the concept of RVO and NRVO (see wikipedia) is well-known, you do raise an interesting point: *How can I know if my return value is copied or not?* -- As far as I know, there is no way to check (except for checking the generated assembly). You have to trust your compiler or use code that doesn't copy. (out params, etc.)

Comment: @Björn: I am mainly interested in my very last question.

Comment: @BjörnPollex - But is it covered on this basic level and with the additional context given (*How can I know*) on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Ben - for your last question, also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140438/is-it-possible-to-ensure-copy-elision

Comment: @Martin, Oli: thanks for the links!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is correct.  And yes, there are situations where it cannot be done, for example:

```
LargeObject getLargeObject()
{
    LargeObject glo1, glo2;
    // do some initialization stuff         
    if (rand() % 2)
        return glo1;
    return glo2;
}
```

It can't be done there because the compiler can't know whether it will use glo1 or glo2 for the return value.

*"How can I know if my return value is copied or not?"*

Two ways I can think of.  You could create noisy copy constructors.  That is, copy constructors that have some detectable side effect, like printing a message.  Then of course there's the old look at the assembly.

Comment: There are even cases where it can do so here. RVO is part of the ABI on many platforms, meaning that the caller reserves the space of the return variable and passes the address. A good compiler will then construct an object at that place at the latest point possible, and when tracing back the execution path, under certain circumstances (e.g. no side-effects of the ctor that need to be considered for that purpose) it can first check the if, and then construct the object in-place. Admittedly, these cases are rare, but compilers these days are improving even here.

Comment: More generally, if there is more than one `return` in the function, some compilers will fail to do RVO.  And of course, if you use both `glo1` and `glo2` within the function, in a way the requires two objects, and sometimes return one, sometimes the other, there's no way the compiler can avoid the copy.

Comment: It is important to note, James Kanze mentions it in his answer, but it is missing here, that there are actually *two* copies, one from the `gloX` to the returned temporary and a separate one from the temporary to the object constructed in `test`. The second copy is what is handled in the ABI as PlasmaHH mentions, and is *always* performed (in all platforms I know), but the first copy depends on the compiler being able to know which of `glo1` or `glo2` will be returned when constructing the object (More [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html))

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should. This is called the named returned value optimization (NRVO or just RVO).

Comment: Yes, in this particular case, it's NRVO since there's a named variable that is returned. RVO is when an instance is created and returned in the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, even a naïve compiler will not “assign to
tlo”, since the standard doesn't allow it.  The formal semantics
of your code involves two copies (both using the copy constructor); the
first from `glo` to a temporary return value, and the second from this
temporary return value to `tlo`.  The standard, however, formally gives
compilers the right to eliminate both of these copies, in this specific
case, and practically speaking, I imagine that all compilers do.

The first copy can be suppressed anytime you return a local variable or
a temporary; some compilers don't do it if there is more than one
`return` in the code, however (but that will never be the case in well 
written code).

The suppression of the second copy depends on the fact that you are
constructing a new object at the call site.  If you're not constructing
a new object, then there may not even be a second copy to suppress; e.g.
in a case like `getLargeObject().memberFunction()`.  If you're assigning
to an existing object, however, there's not much the compiler can do; it
must call the assignment operator.  If the assignment operator copies,
then you get that copy.

Comment: Wow, there's some interesting informations in that answer! I'm not sure though if I get it all right. The first and last sentence seem contradictory to me. Or is it just a language thing?

Comment: @James: *but that will never be the case in well written code* - Wow - no politics at SO! :)

Comment: @Ben The problem is that in the first sentence, I'm using _copy_ in the sense of invoking the copy constructor---I should have been more precise.  In the last sentence, I'm using it in its more general sense: an assignment operator might "copy" a lot of data.  (In fact, a typical assignment operator for a large object might copy construct a new instance, then swap the data.)

Comment: @James: still not clear :( You're not using 'copy' in your first sentence. What's not allowed in the standard? Does RVO only get rid of the first copy operation? If I passed a reference to the called function there would be no copy operation at all... can't it be optimized in a similar way?

Comment: @Ben RVO basically only gets rid of the first copy.  The second copy depends on what you're doing at the call site.  If you're constructing a new object, the compiler can arrange for the returned temporary to be in its place.  If you're doing something else, it generally can't.  What's not allowed by the standard is to not call `operator=` in an assignment; and if you do a copy inside `operator=` (a frequent situation), then this copy cannot be optimized out.